# Get Value of a Nested Key in Dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have a json data and I want to get value of 'account' key using its value. This is what I mean,

```
>>> vd=vxa.json()
>>> vd['outputs']
[{u'account': u'3422VtS7UtCvXYxoXTPnNp8HS6uCHm6j9p86', u'value': 83383165, 
  u'vout': 0}, {u'account': u'3FrWvdxBkrEJKA57UtCvXYxoXrFER53FE', u'vout': 
  1, u'chain': 10, u'isMine': True, u'value': 13155, u'chainIndex': 6}]
```

so I want to get the value for `'3FrWvdxBkrEJKA57UtCvXYxoXrFER53FE`' using the actual account key.

When I did this,

```
>>>vd['outputs']('account':'3FrWvdxBkrEJKA57UtCvXYxoXrFER53FE')['value']
```

I got

```
'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vd['outputs']` is *list* with dictionaries. Assuming that order of this list is stable API, you can do

```
vd['outputs'][1]['value']
```

If order isn't constant, you need to filter with

```
def get_value(account):
    for d in vd['outputs']:
        if d['account'] == account:
            return d['value']
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of 'outputs' is a list. You can iterate over your list.

**Ex:**

```
for i in vd['outputs']:
    if i["account"] == '3FrWvdxBkrEJKA57UtCvXYxoXrFER53FE':
        print(i["value"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see that this is a list, is to format it slightly differently:

```
my_list = [
    {u'account': u'3422VtS7UtCvXYxoXTPnNp8HS6uCHm6j9p86', 
     u'value': 83383165, 
     u'vout': 0}, 
    {u'account': u'3FrWvdxBkrEJKA57UtCvXYxoXrFER53FE', 
     u'vout': 1, 
     u'chain': 10, 
     u'isMine': True, 
     u'value': 13155, 
     u'chainIndex': 6}
]

# 3FrWvdxBkrEJKA57UtCvXYxoXrFER53FE
my_dict = my_list[1]
my_account = my_dict[u'account']
print(my_dict)
print(my_account)
```

output:

```
{'account': '3FrWvdxBkrEJKA57UtCvXYxoXrFER53FE', 'vout': 1, 'chain': 10, 'isMine': True, 'value': 13155, 'chainIndex': 6}
3FrWvdxBkrEJKA57UtCvXYxoXrFER53FE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
value_to_find = '3FrWvdxBkrEJKA57UtCvXYxoXrFER53FE'
for dic in vd['outputs']:
    if dic['account'] == value_to_find:
        print('Value =', dic['value'])
```

Output:

```
Value = 13155
```